# Rails update object using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update an object using rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. But I am getting an error: `Unpermitted parameter: cart_product`
.

I have a `has_many` relationship:

```
has_many :cart_products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_products
```

And have defined my parameters in my Controller:

```
def cart_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(
    cart_product_attributes: [
      :quantity,
      :product_id
    ]
  )
end
```

In my view, I have my form already within a loop `cart_products`.

```
<%= form_for @cart do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for cart_product do |cp| %>
          <%= cp.number_field :quantity, value: cart_product.quantity, min: 1, step: 1, class: "input-quantity"  %>
          <%= cp.hidden_field :product_id, value: cart_product.product_id %>

      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I set the parameters in my form to match the parameters accepted by the controller?

Thankyou.

Comment: I think you may need to specify the name of the association in the fields_for tag. eg. <%= f.fields_for :cart_products, cart_product do |cp| %>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```html
<%= form_for @cart do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for cart_product, @cart.cart_product do |cp| %>
          <%= cp.number_field :quantity, value: cart_product.quantity, min: 1, step: 1, class: "input-quantity"  %>
          <%= cp.hidden_field :product_id, value: cart_product.product_id %>

      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

from rails guides: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for